# jsp fill in field on dropdown item changed

Tags: java, html, jsp

I'm trying to make it so that when an option from the combobox is selected it fills out some of the later input fields. current code (below) doesnt give anny errors just simply does not give output on item changed.

my question being how can I make it so that when selected item changes it fills in some fields.

```
<div>
    options:<select id="optionbox" onchange="Change()">
    <option value="op1">option1</option>
    <option value="op2">option2</option></select><br>

    <form action="KlusServlet.do" method="post"> //not relevant i think used for servlets later on  
        <input id="description" type="text"></input>
    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function Change() {
            var e = document.getElementById("optionbox");
            var selOption = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
            document.getElementById("description").innerHTML = "selected: " + selOption;
        }
    </script>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for textboxes you need to use `.value` not `innerHTML` like below

```
document.getElementById("description").value = "selected: " + selOption;
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use jquery code  `$('#selector').val(value);` for that

[Working Code](http://jsfiddle.net/84WG5/)

```
<div>
            options:<select id="optionbox" onchange="Change()">
            <option value="op1">option1</option>
            <option value="op2">option2</option></select><br>
        <form action="KlusServlet.do" method="post"> //not relevant i think used for servlets later on  
            <input id="description" type="text"></input>
        </form>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function Change() {
                var e = document.getElementById("optionbox");
                var selOption = document.getElementById("optionbox").value;
            alert(selOption);

            $('#description').val(selOption);
            }
        </script>
    </div>
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, unfortunatly jquery is stil something i'm yet to learn on school so can't realy go of and use that in my project

Comment: @Ralan you are welcome.Jquery is js library which makes work easier.